# What is the fastest way to remove child elements from the DOM in IE?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery, and have a table element that contains a few hundred rows. I want to remove all of the rows, and then add a new set of rows. I do this by calling remove and then append on the parent element.

My append logic is fairly fast, and follows the advice given here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

However, the single call to remove takes 5 times as long as the append. What is the fastest way to clear the children of a dom element?

EDIT: Here is a condensed version of the code I use:

```
var table = $('#mytable');
$('tbody', table).remove();
table.append(tBodyContents.join(''));
```

tBodyContents is an array of strings, that when combined will form a the html for the rows in the tbody.

Comment: can you post the code you use to remove all of the rows ?

Comment: Put it in there; sorry I didn't include it before!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function emptyElement(element){
  var i = element.childNodes.length;
  while(i--){
    element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
  }
}
```

this one's actually quicker than the innerHTML trick, can be much quicker, depending on your browser.  there are a few tests up on jsperf using similar functions that will give you some benchmarks...

Comment: I'm not sure why the accepted answer is .html(''), while this is in fact a much quicker solution. Setting innerHTML or .html() to an empty string is in fact considered bad practice exactly because of its performance. To backup my words, here is a test:
http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild/239

Comment: there's also a de-facto standard remove() method which allows to achieve the same - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove

Answer (score 6):

I usually do

```
$('#myTableToEmpty').html('');
```

Then re-add rows where needed.

Comment: Probably faster than $('#myTableToEmpty tr').remove()

Comment: I do the same thing. It's simple and fast. +1

Comment: Does this method clear out bound events and jQuery data as well? That is one thing that (according to the docs) the remove() function does. EDIT: From the docs - *In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.*

Comment: This doesn't seem to be any faster in my case than using remove, but I'll look into it futher.

Comment: It's the worst method because it's the slowest, expecially in IE

Answer (score 4):

What about `$('#tableId').empty()`?

[Documentation for empty method](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Answer (score 1):

If speed is really, really important, you're best of using innerHTML.
$('tbody', table)[0].innerHTML = '';

I personally would just ignore jQuery alltogether, give the body an ID and just go for the document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = '' option. And offcourse still use jQuery for adding.

Comment: I get a "Unknown runtime error" when I try this. I'll see if I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm innerHTML is very much faster to remove huge html from an single element.
In my case :

```
$('#main').html('');  // --> approx 5-6 seconds

$('#main').innerHTML=''; // --> a few milliseconds
```

Thanks for the tips